# Show full HTTP request URI host name in PHP-FPM status page

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, status, fpm

My problem is that `request URI` in the PHP-FPM status page does not show the full request host, and there are multiple domains used on the server, so just showing the path to something is entirely useless if I don't know what domain it is coming from.

All domains send the PHP requests to the server hostname, so I know the server hostname, but not the HTTP request hosts that the status request URI is being given for, which is what I would like to know.

There are over 500 domains, so just trying one-by-one is not an option either.

The current output I get is:

```
$ curl -4k http://localhost/status?full
pool:                 www
process manager:      static
start time:           14/May/2022:22:33:26 +0000
start since:          165698
accepted conn:        2002323
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       8
active processes:     8
total processes:      16
max active processes: 16
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        1823
************************
pid:                  3108690
state:                Running
start time:           16/May/2022:20:18:46 +0000
start since:          978
requests:             877
request duration:     27936
request method:       GET
request URI:          /path/to/request
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /path/to/script.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0
```

Is it possible to show the full request host somewhere? If so, is there any guidance I can use to do so? Thank you in advance!

For the record there is PHP-FPM (fpm-fcgi) with NGINX web server. PHP version: 7.4.28.

Comment: That makes no sense, you're sending a cURL request to the domain so how do you not know the domain? If you want to see DNS records for an IPv4 then use a tool like `nslookup`?

Comment: @Jaquarh sorry for the confusion, I know the server, which is what I am sending the curl request to, but all domains send the PHP requests to the server hostname, so I know the server hostname, but not the HTTP request hosts that the status is being given for.